# $\gcd(f(x),g(x))\neq 1$ iff they share a root in some extension field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

Let $f(x),g(x)\in F[x]$ .  Then  to  prove  that  $(f,g)\neq 1$  iff  there  is  a  field  $E$  containing  both  $F$  and  a  common  root  of  $f(x)\ \ and\ \  g(x)$

Now  if  $$(f(x),g(x))=d(x)\neq 1$$  then the  splitting  field  field  of  $d(x)$  is  our  $E$ .

I  am  not  sure  about  the  converse .  For  if  there  exist  an  $E$  as  said  above  then  $f(x)$  and  $g(x)$  have  $\gcd$ say, $q(x)$ not  equal  to  $1$  in  $E$  .  How  do  I  pull  back  $q(x)$  in  $F$ $?$  What  will  it  look  like  in  $F$  $?$ .

Hope  I  have  conveyed  my  confusion  properly  .

Thanks  for  any  help .

Comment: If $(f,g)= 1$ then there exist $a,b \in F[x]$ with $af+bg=1$, but that would imply $(f,g)=1$ in all extension fields.

Comment: @DerekHolt  :  Thanks.  Now  I  get  it.